# Creating a variable number of class instances

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, copy

My Class:

```
class myClass:
    pass
```

I am looking to recreate this effect:

```
x = myClass()
y = myClass()
z = myClass()
```

within a for loop because the number of times I need to loop will be varied each time.

Trying this:

```
x = 3
for i in range(x):
    cls = myClass()
```

doesn't work because on each iteration I recreate the class instance.

My thinking is that on each loop I need to create a copy of the class and store that in a dict for referencing. So my questions are:

1. Is this the right approach?
2. How do I create a copy of a class?

My attempts to create a class so far have been unsuccessful as the class isn't totally individual.

```
x = deepcopy(cls)
```

```
CopyOfCls = type('CopyOfCls', cls.__bases__, dict(cls.__dict__))
```

EDIT: Answerers revealed that I was actually looking at creating multiple class instances.

Comment: `{k: myClass() for k in 'xyz'}`

Comment: Actually what you are doing is creating instances not classes. Please fix the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to copy a class to make multiple instances of that class.

```
items = []
for i in range(10):
    items.append(myClass())
```

`items` now contains ten separate `myClass` instances. You can access them individually with indexing, ex. `items[3]`.